# What I'm doing wrong with this webscraping code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem in trying to do a webscraping. I'm not very used to programming, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong(but I have some basic knowledge).  I'm trying to do the webscraping with python and beautiful soup. Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'http://www.lotece.com.br/v2/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class = 'dataResultado')
data_name =  soup.find(class = "data branco")
bonus_list = soup.find_all(class = "premio")
number = soup.find(class = "numeros")

for number in bonus_list    
    print(number.prettify())
```

the problem when I try to compile is about synthax. Here is the output:

```
 lotecepx.py", line 6
    results = soup.find(class = 'dataResultado')
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "c:/Users/pvictorml/Documents/lotecepx.py", line 6
    results = soup.find(class = 'dataResultado')
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Also fix for number in bonus_list:

Comment: The method doesn’t take a parameter named `class`, have you read the BeautifulSoup docs?

Answer (score 2):

**`class`** is a reserved keyword.  you can't use keywords as variable names, or as keywords in a function call.

BeautifulSoup works around this by using `class_` instead:

```
bonus_list = soup.find_all(class_="premio")
```

Answer (score 2):

As @reinstate-monica answered, `class` is a reserved word in python.
You can also use:

```
numeros = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : 'numeros'})
for numero in numeros:
    print(numero.text)
```

---

```
9689
3589
2722
...
```

Comment: is there any limit to the data? What is the maximum data I can extract?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes

1. you need to replace `class` with `class_` due to it being a reserved name
2. you forgot a colon after for loop declaration `for number in bonus_list:`
3. numeros class doesnt exist (at least not within "premio")

here is an example of what a working code could look like

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'http://www.lotece.com.br/v2/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_ = 'dataResultado')
data_name =  soup.find(class_ = "data branco")
bonus_list = soup.find_all(class_ = "numeros")

for number in bonus_list:   
    print(number.prettify())
```